# Return a NULL value if Date not in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that counts the number of records imported for every day according to the current date. The only problem is that the count only returns when records have been imported and NULLS are ignored

I have created a CTE with one column in MSSQL that lists dates in a certain range e.g. 2019-01-01 - today.

The query that i've currently got is like this:

```
SELECT TableName, DateRecordImported, COUNT(*) AS ImportedRecords
FROM Table
WHERE DateRecordImported IN (SELECT * FROM DateRange_CTE)
GROUP BY DateRecordImported
```

I get the results fine for the dates that exist in the table for example:

```
TableName  DateRecordImported  ImportedRecords
______________________________________________
Example      2019-01-01         165
Example      2019-01-02         981
Example      2019-01-04         34
Example      2019-01-07         385
....
```

but I need a '0' count returned if the date from the CTE is not in the Table. Is there a better alternative to use in order to return a 0 count or does my method need altering slightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT C.Date, COUNT(t.DateRecordImported) AS ImportedRecords
FROM DateRange_CTE C LEFT JOIN
     table t
     ON t.DateRecordImported = C.Date -- This may differ use actual column name instead
GROUP BY C.Date; -- This may differ use actual column name instead
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I think i was over complicating issues. Also for reference I forgot to cast my dates as a short date to match with the dates in the CTE. Just a heads up for anyone with the same issues!

Answer (score 2):

Move the position of the CTE from a subquery to the FROM:

```
SELECT T.TableName,
       DT.PCTEDateColumn} AS DateRecordImported,
       COUNT(T.{TableIDColumn}) AS ImportedRecords
FROM DateRange_CTE DT
     LEFT JOIN [Table] T ON DT.{TEDateColumn} = T.DateRecordImported
GROUP BY DT.{CTEDateColumn};
```

You'll need to replace the values in braces (`{}`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

SELECT TableName, DateRecordImported, 
        case when DateRecordImported is null 
        then '0' 
        else count(*) end AS ImportedRecords
FROM Table full join DateRange_CTE 
on Table.DateRecordImported DateRange_CTE.ImportedDate
group by DateRecordImported,ImportedDate

(ImportedDate is name of column of CTE)